# How to populate text field with JSON data

Tags: jquery

I have

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 $('#location_search').autocomplete(
    {
     source:'suggest_location.php',
     minLength:1});
    });
```

It returns JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "label" : "EB\u0130 Konukevi",
        "value" : "EB\u0130 Konukevi, 32.791, 39.888",
        "hor" : "32.791",
        "ver" : "39.888"
    },
    {
        "label" : "EB\u0130 Gretwes",
        "value" : "EB\u0130 Gretwes, 32.491, 39.488",
        "hor" : "32.491",
        "ver" : "39.488"
    }
]
```

When I select one of the lacations it populates the location_search field.

How I'll populate the hidden text inputs (with id's ver and hor) with hor and ver when a location is selected?

Comment: which autocomplete plugin are you using?

Comment: You can always set an event handler for the 'open' event:

    $('#location_search').autocomplete({
        source:'suggest_location.php',
        minLength:1
        open: function( event, ui ) {}
    });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you are looking for... Try using the [select event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select):

```
$('#location_search').autocomplete({
    source:'suggest_location.php',
    minLength:1,
    select: function( event, ul ) {
       //do something with hor, ver
       $('#hor').val(ul.item.hor); 
       $('#ver').val(ul.item.ver);
    } 
 });
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/yTMwu/50/